# customizing key filter in sharepoint 2010

Tags: metadata

I am trying to create a key filter on a particular library with columns name, doc level, dept, No., MODIFIED AND MODIFIED BY. I will like the library to filter based on Name,Dept, Doc Type. While trying to create the key filtersi noticed that the configure key filters only has : checked out to, created by, content type, date updated and modified by. How can i customize the "Available key filter fields to include "Name,Dept, Doc Type" that i will like to filter on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Key filters are primarily used by columns of type managed metadata.  They cannot be used for single line of text, multiple line of text, ect.  they can sometimes be used on a choice column if the column only has 1 choice available.  they can also be used on columns for which the values are managed by sharepoint such as Created, Created by, Modified, and Modified by.  and finally, they can be used to filter based on content type.

I would guess that your name column is of type single line of text.  that definitely won't be available as a key filter.  if Dept and Doc Type aren't managed metadata, they won't be available either.